# using django, i want to show the user options to pick from with 'select' and a TextChoices model

Tags: python, django, user-interface, django-models, django-views

in my html template i have a select box where the user chooses the desired size of clothing like this

```
<select>
    <option> Small </option>
    <option> Medium </option>
    <option> Large </option>
</select>
```

i want to **display** the options for the user to see.

because i want to save the input in the database, to grab it, i was thinking of doing this:

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    class Size(models.TextChoices):
        SMALL = 'S'
        MEDIUM = 'M'
        LARGE = 'L'
    size = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=Size.choices, default=Size.LARGE)
```

html

```
<select>

    {% for size in product.size %}
        <option value="" name="{{ size }}">
            {{ size }}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}

</select>
```

views.py

```
def product(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'product/product.html', {'product': product})
```

but i only get to display one value, which is the default value LARGE

in my admin page, the 'Sizes' dropdown select for the product is showing perfectly with all 3 different values for the admin to pick

did i choose the wrong method with 'TextChoices'? the html is not correct? am i missing something in views.py?
all of the above?

Answer (score 0):

So... i found a way to do it...

using django forms

```
from django import forms
from .models import Product

class ClothingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['size']
```

views.py

```
from .forms import ClothingForm

def product(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    sizesForm = ClothingForm()
    return render(request, 'product/product.html', {'product': product, 'sizesForm': sizesForm})
```

html

```
{{ sizesForm }}
```

damn im dumb